# How to aggregate series and define colors in a bar chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, aggregate, bar-chart, series

I am trying to create a bar chart (in Google Sheet) defining and aggregating different series.

I was able to create the different series (ranges), however, as you may see, the aggregation works partially. 
As a matter of fact, it sums only the first 2 values (rows). If the series has 3 values [apricots], the function will aggregate only the first 2

Moreover, the colors are not properly associated with the right stages. I presume the function “aggregatedValues” is once again responsible.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FwDcJuBBsXsPMASxhKxUWDKxv55U5zFKnswtltRkjJA/edit#gid=0

---

```
//Different fruit definition
var fruit = ["Bananas", "strawberries", "Apricots", "Peas"]
var eachpair = fruit


//Agreggation of values based on fruit and add color for each stage
function aggregatefruit(range){
var count = 0
var aggregatedValues = []
var eachfruit = fruit
var eachValue = range
fruit.forEach(function (eachfruit){
              count = 0
              range.forEach(function (eachValue){
                      if(eachValue[0]==eachfruit)
                      {
                      count=count+1
                       }
                       })
      if(count > 0){
       aggregatedValues.push([eachfruit,count])
   }  
                                  })
 return aggregatedValues
  } 

//Different fruit definition
var fruit = ["Bananas", "Kiwi", "Apricots", "Peas"]
var eachpair = fruit


//Agreggation of values based on fruit and add color for each stage
function aggregatefruit(range){
 var count = 0
 var aggregatedValues = []
 var eachfruit = fruit
 var eachValue = range
 fruit.forEach(function (eachfruit){
              count = 0
              range.forEach(function (eachValue){
                      if(eachValue[0]==eachfruit)
                      {
                      count=count+1
                       }
                       })
      if(count > 0){
       aggregatedValues.push([eachfruit,count])
  }  
                                  })
 return aggregatedValues
 } 


 //Gets the color based on the different fruit
  function getColor(fruit){
  var color = "White";
  var colorArray = [];

 fruit.forEach(function(eachPair){
 if (eachPair[0] == "Bananas"){color = "yellow";}
 else if (eachPair[0] == "Kiwi"){color = "brown";}
 else if (eachPair[0] == "Apricots"){color = "orange";}  
 else if (eachPair[0] == "Peas"){color = "green";} 
 colorArray.push(color)
  }) 
 return colorArray;
  };

 //Draws bar chart based on fruit
 function createStageChart() {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 //Get current sheet
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 //Get values for aggregation
 var range = sheet.getRange("C3:D11")
 var values = range.getValues().sort()
 var aggregatedValues = aggregatefruit(values);
 var colorfruit = getColor(aggregatedValues);


//Automatically creating several ranges per series
 var position = 3
 var index = 0
 var chart = 
sheet.newChart().asBarChart().setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
.setPosition(10, 10, 0, 0)
.setNumHeaders(0)
.build();
 sheet.insertChart(chart)


 aggregatedValues.forEach(function(eachfruit){
 chart = chart.modify()
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("C"+position.toString()+":D"+ . 
 (position+eachfruit[2]-1).toString()))
    .setOption('applyAggregateData',index)
    .build();
 sheet.updateChart(chart);
 index=index+1
 position=position+eachfruit[2]
  })
  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('applyAggregateData',0)
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
    }
```

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: You are right, however I will be more than happy to give you access. Could you please send the request? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As for the first part of your question - the bar chart will sum your values correctly, if you setup the chart to combine ranges vertically instead of horizontally. You can achieve it with Apps Script by implementing the method

```
.setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
```

in your chart builder. See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder#setmergestrategymergestrategy

For additional information on how to define colors, please consult this information:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole

Comment: The method .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)  works well! It actually aggregates all the values! 
Nevertheless, now I am not able to assign the colour to each series. Simply because, once the rows are merged, they don’t exist anymore! The output is 1 unique series. 
Ideally, there would be a method to create what, in the customize menu is known, as “(Format)data point”.
Once again thanks a lot since now!

Comment: As for customazing colors, please have a look at this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892163/setting-bar-border-color-and-weight-using-gas-charts